# How do I calculate the Adjusted R-squared score using scikit-learn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm already using the [r2_score](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.r2_score.html) function but don't understand how I can get the "adjusted" R^2 score from this. The description at this page doesn't mention it - maybe it's the adjusted score by default?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Adjusted R2 requires number of independent variables as well. That's why it will not be calculated using such an independent metrics function (as we are not providing, how ypred was calculated).

However you can calculate the adjusted R2 from R2 with a simple formula given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination#Adjusted_R2)

[image]

where n is number of observations in sample and p is number of independent variables in model

Comment: smth like this should work: 

```from sklearn.metrics import r2_score  
r2_score(y_test, y_pred)  
print(1-(1-r2_score(y_test, y_pred))*((len(X_test)-1)/(len(X_test)-len(X_test[0])-1)))```

Comment: @JohnSonnino This code is for evaluation on the tests set?

Comment: @JohnSonnino also `len(X_test[0])`does not gives the feature numbers for pandas dataframe. Instead use `len(X_test.columns)` or `X_test.shape[1]`.

Comment: Hi @Aritesh, I got a question regarding this formula. I understand how to calculate it, but is p, the number of independent variables without enconding? Or after encoding?

I might have 3 categorical independent variables (2 of them binary features, and other with 3 levels), but will p be 3 here? Or it will be the amount of final features? It will be 4 independent variables after encoding?

Answer (score 10):

alternatively...

```
# adjusted R-squared
1 - ( 1-model.score(X, y) ) * ( len(y) - 1 ) / ( len(y) - X.shape[1] - 1 )
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Simple calculation of Adj. R2

```
Adj_r2 = 1 - (1-r2_score(y, y_pred)) * (len(y)-1)/(len(y)-X.shape[1]-1)
```

Comment: what do you mean by y, which y are we supposed to use as the number of samples. Is it y_test or y_train or is it len(y_test) + len(y_train)

Comment: @SamuelThomas It should be whichever sample you want to compute the adj. r^2 square for. The `y_test` above should really just be `y` to indicate the array of outcomes for the sample you're trying to score. `y_pred` would be the predicted outcomes for the same.

Comment: I also have a question about y and y-test that you mentioned in the post. If I understand correctly, you mean for calculating r-squre we should just use y_test. But for calculating the Adj_r2, we should use the whole y and X for len(y), X.shape[1], I mean before split the data. Is that right? or you mean:                                            Adj_r2 = 1 - (1-r2_score(y_test, y_pred)) * (len(y_train)-1)/(len(y_train)-X_train.shape[1]-1)

Answer (score 2):

The wikipedia [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination#Adjusted_R2) has been revised over the course of time in regards to this formula. To match the current state this would be the appropriate formula:

Adj r2 = 1-(1-R2)*(n-1)/(n-p)

with sklearn you could write some re-usable code such as :

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score

def r2(actual: np.ndarray, predicted: np.ndarray):
    """ R2 Score """
    return r2_score(actual, predicted)

def adjr2(actual: np.ndarray, predicted: np.ndarray, rowcount: np.int, featurecount: np.int):
    """ R2 Score """
    return 1-(1-r2(actual,predicted))*(rowcount-1)/(rowcount-featurecount)
```

Comment: unfortunately this does not really answer how to do it with scikit-learn as asked in the question

Comment: @n4321d I revised to have some scikit-learn fun in it