# How to get Adjusted R Square for Linear Regression

Tags: data-science

Using sklearn.metrics I can compute R square.How I can compute Adjusted Adjusted R square using Linear Regression model?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I calculate the Adjusted R-squared score using scikit-learn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49381661/how-do-i-calculate-the-adjusted-r-squared-score-using-scikit-learn)

Answer (score 5):

Scikit-Learn's Linear Regression does not return the adjusted R squared. However, from the R -squared you can calculate the adjusted R squared from the formula:

[image]

Where p is the number of predictors (also known as features or explanatory variables) and n is the number of data points. So if your data is in a dataframe called train and you have r-squared, `r2`, the formula would be:

```py
adj_r2 = (1 - (1 - r2) * ((train.shape[0] - 1) / 
          (train.shape[0] - train.shape[1] - 1)))
```

`train.shape[0]` is the number of observations, and `train.shape[1]` is the number of features.

The [StatsModels](http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/install.html) library has a linear regression method that does return the adjusted R squared (among many other metrics). [Here is the documentation.](http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.RegressionResults.html)

The formula above is from [this Stack Exchange Answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/63097/157316) which says this is known as *Wherry Formula - 1*. There are a number of different formulas used to calculate adjusted R squared, but this is the method used in R. For more on the differences between adjusted R squared methods, see the answer linked to or the paper [Estimating 
R^2 Shrinkage in Regression](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/28ad/ba1ecb06d4cb7c3731a09bd4b257d8bf4918.pdf)

Comment: Please let me know whether I can compute this using any Python package or I need to compute manually.

Comment: Yes, I have modified my answer to include the StatsModel library option. However, if you already have the r squared from Scikit-Learn, it is a good idea to see how to calculate the adjusted R squared value yourself so you know the difference!

Comment: shouldn't the `.shape`'s be swapped for `n` and `p`? `n` = Number of observations, but `shape[1]` is the number of features. They look backwards. Also if we have `r2 ` already, do we need to square it *again*??? Let me know if I'm way wrong here!

Comment: @MattR the rows contain the observations so `shape[0]` is the number of observations. The columns contain the features so `shape[1]` is the number of features. The equation written in code should be correct.

Squaring the `R^2` is part of the formula to calculate the adjusted R squared.

Comment: @willk - I think something happened to your post during an edit. I can no longer see the formula. And I cannot rollback the edits - It somehow disappeared from all the versions.

Comment: My fault, I've fixed the formula, and you were right, there was a mistake where `shape[1]` was switched for `shape[0]`. It _should_ be correct now, but please let me know if it is not.

Comment: @willk - you do not need to square `r2`. if the `r2` variable is that: squaring `r`, then it should not be then squared *again*. So if `r2` is coming from another result it should be changed from `(1 - r2 ** 2)` to `1-r2`

Comment: @MattR Acknowledged and fixed. Thanks for the correction

Comment: hi @willk, I believe the formula above needs to account for the number of parameters in each model. For instance, if you are fitting a 3rd degree polynomial on a single dependent variable, you will have `p = 3` (3 fitted parameters + intercept). If you have multiple features, each of which is fitted like this, we will have `p = 3*n_feats`. 
[More information](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/41138/calculating-adjusted-r2-in-polynomial-linear-regression-with-single-variable)

Comment: If I need to evaluate on the test set I need `n` and `p` from test set?

Comment: Going by the formula of adjusted R-square, can we say for a very high value of ```n``` (data points), adjusted R-square and R-square will be same