# How to calculated the adjusted R2 value using scikit

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression

I have a dataset for which I have to develop various models and compute the adjusted R2 value of all models.

```
    cv = KFold(n_splits=5,shuffle=True,random_state=45)
    r2 = make_scorer(r2_score)
    r2_val_score = cross_val_score(clf, x, y, cv=cv,scoring=r2)
    scores=[r2_val_score.mean()]
    return scores
```

I have used the above code to calculate the R2 value of every model. 
But I am more interested to know the adjusted R2 value of every models 
Is there any package in python which can do the job?

I will appreciate your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get Adjusted R Square for Linear Regression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51023806/how-to-get-adjusted-r-square-for-linear-regression)

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49381661/how-do-i-calculate-the-adjusted-r-squared-score-using-scikit-learn/49381947

Answer (score 32, accepted):

you can calculate the adjusted R2 from R2 with a simple formula given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination#Adjusted_R2).

```
Adj r2 = 1-(1-R2)*(n-1)/(n-p-1)
```

Where `n` is the sample size and `p` is the number of independent variables.

Adjusted R2 requires number of independent variables as well. That's why it will not be calculated using this function.

Comment: Thanks ,  so I assume n = number of sample size , p = number of independent variables

Comment: When we want to calculate adjusted R2 for each fold during cross-validation, will `n` correspond to the size of the dataset or the size of the fold? (e.g., 80% of the number of rows if we are doing 5-fold CV) @min2bro

Comment: @nvergos n should correspond to the size of the fold.

Comment: Should I use `n`and `p` of train set if I am evaluating for train or test set. Or I should use `n`and `p` for train set if I am evaluating for train set and use test set `n`and `p` if I am evaluating for test set?

Comment: @vasili111 we check the model performance on test data, so its better to check the adjusted r2 and r2 on test data.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the wikipedia has been revised over the course of time in regards to Adjusted R2 formula.  To match the current state of the wikipedia link [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination#Adjusted_R2) this would be the appropriate formula:

Adj r2 = 1-(1-R2)*(n-1)/(n-p)  **notice last part is (n-p) instead of (n-p-1)

where:

n = count of rows in your dataset used for train or test
p = count of independent variables